# Laravel Validation (unique rule)

Tags: validation, laravel

i use a separate class for validation so it looks like

```php
class UserValidation {

    protected static $id;

    protected static $rules = [
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users,email,{{ self::$id }}',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:4',
    ];

    public static function validate($input, $id)
    {
        self::$id = $id;
        return Validator::make($input, self::$rules);
    }
}
```

so imagine a user wants to update only his password ,so he updates it > submit but then he receive the error `this email is already taken` ,because laravel cant read `{{ self::$id }}` ,so how do i solve something like that.

Comment: A quick solution would be to use [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent#effortless-validation-with-ardent).

Comment: Ardent would have the same problem as it uses laravel own validation syntax ,it basically does the same as i did but in a more laravel-ish way.

Comment: My mistake, I linked to the wrong section [https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent#updates-with-unique-rules](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent#updates-with-unique-rules).

Comment: not to repeat my self so check http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique but i need to use a dynamic id not a static integer.

Comment: I understood that, but if you use the `updateUnique` instead of the regular `update` method, Ardent will use the ID from the model your are validating, without the need for you to specify it manually in the validation rule. The example there is showing exactly what you are trying to achieve. From the Ardent docs: "_Note that in the above example of the rules, we did not tell the Validator which table or even which field to use as it is described in the Laravel Documentation (ie unique:users,email,10). **Ardent is clever enough to figure it out**._".

Comment: ahaaa ,i just noticed that ,thanx for the heads-up ,i will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do your trick

```php
class UserValidation {

    protected static $rules = [
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:4',
    ];

    public static function validate($input, $id = false)
    {
        $rules = self::$rules;

        if ($id) {
            $rules['email'] .= ",$id";
        }

        return Validator::make($input, $rules);
    }
}
```

If you are passing an id it will appended to the rules array if not then a simple rules array will be used. I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: This will work but only once, if the validation is run a second time within the same request, the ID will be appended again (twice) to the rule. It might be best to modify a copy of the rules, and pass that to the `Validator::make` (something like `$rules = self::rules;` and modify/use that).

Comment: @Alley that did work so thanx ,@Bogdan can u plz post an example ?

Comment: You can store the ID wherever you want, but you'll still need to use a copy the rules inside the `validate` method, because the `id` will still need to be appended to the rule string. So that doesn't affect the solution @Alley Shairu posted.

Comment: @ctf0 I've modified Alley's answer with the fixes I proposed.